# Two flags rejected without a reason

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

I have two flags rejected without any reason and one of the questions was deleted.

1. [How to create a matrix dynamically in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43620371/how-to-create-a-matrix-dynamically-in-r) 
   This was flagged as off-topic
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42141686/c-sharp-wrapper-method-to-run-methods-as-synchronously-tasks
   This was flagged as very low quality

I've been thinking the reason to understand why I shouldn't flag that kind of question but is not very clear.

Hope you can help me to understand.

Comment: Do note that VLQ is for stuff that is basically gibberish.  IMHO the second one should have been flagged as Too Broad.

Comment: @NathanOliver is correct. If your "very low quality" flag on the second question would have been handled by a moderator, it would have been declined. Only difference would be you'd have seen a reason attached to the decline. The "very low quality" flag is basically meant for things that need to be immediately deleted by a moderator. That question doesn't qualify; it just needs to be closed, so a "recommend closure" flag would have been more appropriate. (Moderators don't handle "recommend closure" flags; they are exclusively reviewed by the community.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you don't receive a reason for a declined flag, just a notice of "declined", that almost always indicates that your flag was declined by community review. Here are the two reviews that led to those flags being declined:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/15948838
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/15158947

The latter question was removed by the system automatically after being downvoted and having no answers for an extended period of time. The former appears to have been edited into shape and seems to have received good answers.

Per request, here's an image of the deleted question's review, which might not be available to everyone:

[image: Review of second item in list]